# Collapsible form not working in bootstrap, materialize

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, materialize

I found this code on Codepen and it seems to work fine there but when I use it for one of my projects it expands the form on page load. I want the form's initial state to be collapsed and then expanded when I click on a button. Please help with this.

I tried some jquery stuff but I am pretty new to it hence I am here. I am not using the scss I am using just materialize, bootstrap and jquery.

I want the form to be collapsed initially as the example shows on codepen- https://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/ebxhm

```
<html>
    <div class="expansive-button v1">
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-2x"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="expansive">
        <h3>Advanced Options</h3>
        <input placeholder="Advanced Option #1">
        <input placeholder="Advanced Option #2">
    </div>

</html>

<script>
    $(".v1").unbind('click').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
        $(this).next().stop().animate({
            height: "toggle",
            opacity: "toggle"
        }, "slow");
    });

</script>
```

Comment: can you provide codepen of your project

Comment: Sorry but I cannot, I work on a separate domain which does not have the internet access and I cannot copy the code from that domain to this one (company policy). If you have some specific question that you want to ask I would be more than happy to answer.

Comment: @NishargShah I can rewrite the code on codepen give me some time.

Comment: https://codepen.io/harsh1930/pen/LaEJeZ here is the codepen, sorry for the extremely delayed reply, I know that the code is not working as it should be since I am not using the scss but then what should I write in css or javascript to get the initial state collapsed for the div?